# Consultar fecha sin año SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

tengo esta tabla, deben cargarse imágenes que serán elegidas según la fecha o el rango de fechas.

El problema es que quiero elegir por ejemplo la de "/bannerfiestas" que está dentro de un rango, pero todos los años.

La consulta que hice fue:

```
SELECT imagen FROM imagenbanner 
WHERE activo AND NOT eliminado
AND *fechaDeHoy* BETWEEN fechaInicio AND fechaFin
```

El *fechaDeHoy* se reemplaza por ? en `java` porque consulta la fecha con LocalDate.now()

Lo ideal seria que tome solo mes y dia para que pueda realizar la consulta todos los años sin tener que modifar la DB todos los años

[image: image1]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Entonces obviamente no podes usar between, salvo que saques el año de la ecuacion transformado la fecha a cadena de la forma mmdd... lo intentaste????

Comment: Suponiendo que las columnas son de tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME` puedes escribir una consulta que verifique sólo mes y día, algo como: `WHERE MONTH(laColumnaFecha) = elParametro AND DAY(laColumnaFecha) = elParametro`
 . Revisa las funciones como `MONTH()`  y `DAY()` de tu SGBD.

Answer (score -1):

Podrias crearte un campo en la tabla que fuese numerico as integer (4). Al cargar los campos de la tabla de imagenes, tendrias que quedarte con el mes de la fecha y el dia de la imagen. Por ejemplo el mes 8 y el dia 15. Concatenar como string "8" & "15", pasarla a numerico(815) y grabar en el nuevo campo numerico. En la consulta Select podrias consultar por numeros solo la parte mesdia >= and <= .Espero que mas o menos te oriente si no encuentras algo mejor.

Comment: no sirve.. que harias por ejemplo con fechas como el 11 de febrero.. o el primero de diciembre?? el numero seria el mismo ;) si concatenas al reves, 11 de febrero es igual al 12 de enero ;

Comment: Hacer esto sería redundancia de datos, sobrecargando la tabla sin necesidad cuando el problema se puede resolver desde los datos que ya existen.

Comment: Trabajar con numero en vez de con fechas tiene sus ventajas. Hace 30 años el mayor problema que tenia un programador era el espacio en disco y por supuesto mirábamos los caracteres como si de nuestro dinero se tratara. Ahora el problema es la velocidad y seguramente dentro de 20 años se tendrá otro problema. Los procesos con números son mas rápidos en cualquier leguaje de programación.